# Why do some fonts sit higher on the line to others

Tags: html, css, fonts, typeface

When I change the font for this button, depending on the font it seems that the text is sitting at different heights. For example “helvetica” sits central (vertically) but “bebas neue” (and other fonts to different degrees) seems to be raised up from the baseline. When I select the text for the button and I can see the highlighted area, the letters are not sat to the bottom of it, they are raised up. Vertical align does nothing either.

My question is, is this the fault of font developers? Ie are some font developers counting for example the bottom of the letter “y” as the bottom of the line and others counding the bottom of the letter “v” as the bottom of the line?? I am very confused.

```
<button id=“but1”>Some text</button>

<style>
 #but1{
  padding:2%;
  background:black;
  color:white;
  font-family: helvetica;
  line-heigh:normal;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: I would say each font is unique ... they don't have the same glyph so you cannot blame them from being different, it's in fact the purpose

Comment: Thank you do you have any recommended reading, not sure about terms like “glyph” so don’t know where to start googling. Thanks

Comment: you can start here : https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/45162/what-is-the-difference-between-glyph-and-font ;)